# Why is free() not freeing up RAM on my Arduino Uno

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, arduino

I'm trying to free up RAM by removing a variable after it is used with the free() function, yet my RAM is not cleaning up.  I suppose there is no garbage cleanup taking place?  The space cleans up after I exit the section of code (scoped if-statement, while-loop or function), but not the free() statement itself.

I'm doing the following to check the RAM:

```
int freeRam () {
  extern int __heap_start, *__brkval; 
  int v; 
  return (int) &v - (__brkval == 0 ? (int) &__heap_start : (int) __brkval); 
}
```

Additionally, how would one 'free' up such memory?

Comment: What Arduino are you using? Did you see: [Arduino Playground - Available Memnory](http://arduino.cc/playground/Code/AvailableMemory): _In order to determine the amount of memory currently available the most accurate result can be found by using this MemoryFree library._

Comment: I played with that lib as well, though typically got different results.  Perhaps the answer below answers why I got different results....

Comment: Yes, the comment by @GregHewgill does better address it.

Comment: *" I suppose there is no garbage cleanup taking place"* By default c++ has not garbage collection. I don't know the environment you are working in, but...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't expect the `__brkval` to decrease just because you called `free()` on a single memory block. The memory block will be *marked* as free and available for reuse, but in general the `__brkval` will only move in one direction according to the *maximum* amount of memory that your program uses at any one time.

Comment: How does one actually go about 'freeing it up'?  I suppose I shoudl edit my question as well as that was a 'poorly' implied follow-on question. :)

Comment: @WildBill: Don't. The OS knows better than you do how best to manage its memory. (Arguably.)

Comment: @WildBill: Since the Arduino isn't multitasking, there isn't much reason to *really* free the memory (that is, by decreasing `__brkval`). Furthermore, the only way the memory manager could decrease `__brkval` at all would be if you free the very *last* block in the heap space. Otherwise, in the general case if you free a block in the middle, there is no memory compaction going on.